# Spigot 1.9 activate commandblocks using pressureplates

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands, minecraft-java-edition-server, minecraft-spigot, minecraft-worldguard

On my Spigot server I have a pressure plate that is activating a command-block. The problem is that only ops can activate it. If non-ops try to activate it the server says:

```
"HEY! You can't use that here."
```

Is there a permission that allows non-op players to use it? I use PermissionEX, Vault, Worldguard and Essentials.

Comment: Have you given non-ops' a build/interact permission node?

Comment: Only build note, but it only appears when the pressureplate is connected to a command-block

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was Worldguard. I had to add "/region flag **global** use allow" to my region.

Comment: You can click the green check mark to select this as being the final answer.

Comment: Only after 2 days (iirc) because this is his own answer. After that it is possible :)